# SQl query optimzation

Tags: sql, sql-server, streamsets

*can anyone help me optimizing the query. I am using this query in an ETL called streamsets and it is yielding 70 records for 6 minutes when i run an streamsets pipleline which is very slow.we are taking this query from an SSIS package and joining each of the tables using left outer joins.I need to optimize it so that it fetches atleast 1000 records per minute in streamsets  *

```
 SELECT [FR].[ORDER_ID]
    , [FR].[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID]
    , [SR].[SCREENING_RESULT_ID]
    , [AT].[AG_TASK_ID]
    , [RCC].[RESULT_CRIM_CASE_ID]
    , [RCC].[RESULT_CRIM_CHARGE_ID]
    , [FR].[JURISDICTION_ID]
    , [COUNTY] = CASE WHEN [FR].[PRODUCT_ID] = 2 THEN [JC].[COUNTY_NAME] ELSE '' END
    , [STATE] = CASE WHEN [FR].[PRODUCT_ID] = 2 THEN [JC].[STATE_A2_CD] ELSE [JS].[STATE_A2_CD] END
    , [JT].[JURISDICTION_TYPE_NAME]
    , [FR].[PRODUCT_ID]
    , [P].[PRODUCT_NAME]
    , [FR].[ORGANIZATION_ID]
    , [O].[ORGANIZATION_NAME]
    , [SA].[SALARY_RANGE]
    , [AGE] = YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR([FR].[SUBJECT_DOB])
    , [FR].[SUBJECT_JOB_COUNTRY]
    , [FR].[SUBJECT_JOB_STATE]
    , [FR].[ENTRY_DATE]
    , [FR].[CREATION_DATE]
    , [FR].[CLOSED_DATE]
    , [FR].[EXTERNAL_USER_ID]
    , [FR].[GENDER_CODE_ID]
    , [GC].[GENDER_CODE_VALUE]
    , [AT].[DATA_SOURCE]
    , [SU].[RESEARCHER_CLASS]
    , [TT].[TASK_TYPE]
    , [TT].[TASK_DESCRIPTION]
    , [RCC].[CHARGE_DESCRIPTION]
    , [RCC].[DISPOSITION_DESCRIPTION]
    , [P].[GENERAL_LEDGER_NBR]
    , [O].[SCHEME_AGENCY_ID]
    , [RT].[RESULT_TYPE_ID]
    , [RT].[RESULT_CATEGORY]
    , [RT].[RESULT_TYPE]
    , [SU].[USER_ID]
    ,FR.AG_STATUS_ID
    , [SCREENING_REFERENCE_ID]=CAST(LEFT([FR].[SCREENING_REFERENCE_ID],250) AS VARCHAR(8000))
    ,[P1].POD_NAME
    , ATH.AG_TASK_HISTORY_ID
    ,ATH.TASK_STATUS TASK_HISTORY_STATUS
    , ATH.AG_TASK_DATE TASK_HISTORY_DATE
    ,[TT].[TASK_TYPE_ID]
    ,ATH.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID
    ,ATH.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID
    ,'' AS [STATUS NOTES]
    , FR.SCOPE_OF_SEARCH
    , SR.COMMONNAMFLAG
    ,CASE WHEN SU.RESEARCHER_CLASS = 'EXTERNAL' THEN SU.[USER_ID] END AS VENDOR
    , CASE [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID WHEN 14 THEN 'SD IN' WHEN 15 THEN 'MR' WHEN 1 THEN 'ER' END AS [REQUIRED_ACTION]
    , CASE
                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 1    THEN
                                    CASE ATH.TASK_STATUS
                                    WHEN 'DOCUMENTUPLOADED' THEN 'FMT RECORD ENTRY'
                                    WHEN 'ACKNOWLEDGED' THEN 'SEARCHES'
                                    WHEN 'AWAITINGHITENTRY' THEN 'AWAITING HIT'
                                    WHEN 'DISPUTE' THEN 'AWAITING HIT'
                                    WHEN 'DOUBLEENTERRESULTS' THEN 'AWAITING HIT'
                                    WHEN 'NEW' THEN 'SEARCHES'
                                    WHEN 'SOURCEUNAVAILABLE' THEN 'SEARCHES'
                                    WHEN 'UPLOADED' THEN 'SEARCHES'
                                    END
                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 15 THEN
                                    CASE ATH.TASK_STATUS
                                    WHEN 'DISPUTE' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'DOCUMENTUPLOADED' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'DOUBLESMARTDATAREVIEW' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'MANUALREVIEW' THEN 'QC'
                                    END
                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 14 THEN
                                    CASE ATH.TASK_STATUS
                                    WHEN 'DISPUTE' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'INFONEEDED' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'INFOPROVIDED' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'INFONEEDEDACK' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'NEW' THEN 'QC'
                                    WHEN 'SDINFONEEDED' THEN 'CD COMPLIANCE'
                                    END
                          END AS [AOM STATUS]
    , CASE
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 1 AND
                                                     ATH.TASK_STATUS = 'DOCUMENTUPLOADED' AND
                                                    ATH.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND
                                                    ATH.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'ER DOCUMENT UPLOADED COMPLETE'
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 14 AND
                                                     ATH.TASK_STATUS = 'INFONEEDED' THEN 'SD INFO NEEDED INFO NEEDED DATA'
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 1 AND SU.RESEARCHER_CLASS = 'INTERNAL' AND
                                         FR.AG_STATUS_ID NOT IN (152) THEN 'ER INTERNAL'
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 1 AND
                                                     ATH.TASK_STATUS = 'AWAITINGHITENTRY' AND
                                                     ATH.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND
                                                     ATH.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID IS NOT NULL AND
                                                     ATH.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID = ATH.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID THEN 'ER AWAITING HIT ENTRY DATA'
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 14 THEN 'SD INFO NEEDED DATA'
                                    WHEN [TT].TASK_TYPE_ID = 15 AND
                                                     ATH.TASK_STATUS = 'INFONEEDED' THEN 'MR INFO NEEDED'
                                                                    END AS AG_OPS_STATUS
    , FR.EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID
    , AOT.OTD
    , drv_pod_name=[P1].POD_NAME
    , TAT_IN_MIN= Case when TAT_IN_MIN < 0 then 0 else  TAT_IN_MIN end
    , SU2.USER_ID CF_SYS_USER
    , SU3.USER_ID MODIFIED_SYS_USER
    , GETDATE() GET_DATE
    FROM AG_TASK_HISTORY [ATH] LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
                    (
                                    (
                                                    (
                                                                    (
                                                                                    (
                                                                                                    (
                                                                                                                    (
                                                                                                                                    (
                                                                                                                                    SELECT [ORDER_ID] ,[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID],[JURISDICTION_ID],[PRODUCT_ID],[ORGANIZATION_ID],[SUBJECT_DOB],[SUBJECT_JOB_COUNTRY],[SUBJECT_JOB_STATE],[ENTRY_DATE],[CREATION_DATE],[CLOSED_DATE],[EXTERNAL_USER_ID],[GENDER_CODE_ID],AG_STATUS_ID,[SCREENING_REFERENCE_ID],SCOPE_OF_SEARCH,EXTERNAL_ORDER_ID,POD_ID,[SALARY_RANGE_ID],[JURISDICTION_TYPE]
                                                                                                                                    FROM [FULFILLMENT_REQUEST]
                                                                                                                                    ) FR
                                                                                                                                    LEFT JOIN
                                                                                                                                    (
                                                                                                                                                    (SELECT [SCREENING_RESULT_ID],[RESULT_TYPE_ID],[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID],COMMONNAMFLAG FROM [SCREENING_RESULT] )[SR]
                                                                                                                                                    INNER JOIN [DBO].[RESULT_TYPE] [RT]
                                                                                                                                                    ON [RT].[RESULT_TYPE_ID] = [SR].[RESULT_TYPE_ID]
                                                                                                                                    )
                                                                                                                                    ON [SR].[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID] = [FR].[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID]
                                                                                                                    )
                                                                    INNER JOIN [PRODUCT] [P]
                                                                    ON [P].[PRODUCT_ID] = [FR].[PRODUCT_ID]
                                                                    INNER JOIN [ORGANIZATION] [O]
                                                                    ON [O].[ORGANIZATION_ID] = [FR].[ORGANIZATION_ID]
                                                                    LEFT JOIN(
                                                                                    (SELECT [AG_TASK_ID],[DATA_SOURCE],[TASK_TYPE_ID],[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID],[SYSTEM_USER_ID] FROM [AG_TASK] ) [AT]
                                                                                    INNER JOIN [TASK_TYPE] [TT]
                                                                                    ON [TT].[TASK_TYPE_ID] = [AT].[TASK_TYPE_ID]
                                                                    )
                                                                    ON [AT].[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID] = [FR].[FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID])
                                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                                                                                    (SELECT [RESULT_CRIM_CASE_ID],[SCREENING_RESULT_ID] FROM [RESULT_CRIM_CASE])[RC]
                                                                                    INNER JOIN (SELECT [RESULT_CRIM_CASE_ID],[RESULT_CRIM_CHARGE_ID],[CHARGE_DESCRIPTION],[DISPOSITION_DESCRIPTION] FROM [RESULT_CRIM_CHARGE]) [RCC]
                                                                                    ON [RCC].[RESULT_CRIM_CASE_ID] = [RC].[RESULT_CRIM_CASE_ID]
                                                                    )
                                                                    ON [SR].[SCREENING_RESULT_ID] = [RC].[SCREENING_RESULT_ID]
                                                                    )
                                                                    )
                                                                    LEFT JOIN [SYSUSER] [SU]
                                                                    ON [SU].[SYSTEM_USER_ID] = [AT].[SYSTEM_USER_ID]
                                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [SALARY_RANGE] [SA]
                                                                    ON [SA].[SALARY_RANGE_ID] = [FR].[SALARY_RANGE_ID]
                                                    )
                                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [JURISDICTION_TYPE] [JT]
                                                    ON [JT].[JURISDICTION_TYPE_ID] = [FR].[JURISDICTION_TYPE]
                                    )
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [GENDER_CODE] [GC]
                                    ON [GC].[GENDER_CODE] = [FR].[GENDER_CODE_ID]
                    )
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [JURISDICTION_COUNTY] [JC]
                    ON [JC].[JURISDICTION_ID] = [FR].[JURISDICTION_ID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [JURISDICTION_STATE] [JS]
                    ON [JS].[JURISDICTION_ID] = [FR].[JURISDICTION_ID]
    )
    ON [ATH].AG_TASK_ID=[AT].AG_TASK_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [POD] [P1] ON [FR].POD_ID = [P1].POD_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
                    SELECT *, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [IN_DATE], [IP_DATE]))-(DATEDIFF(WK, [IN_DATE], [IP_DATE]) * (2*24*60))-
                    (CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, [IN_DATE]) = 'SUNDAY'
                    THEN (24*60) ELSE 0 END)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, [IP_DATE]) = 'SATURDAY'
                    THEN (24*60) ELSE 0 END) TAT_IN_MIN
                    FROM (
                                    SELECT FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID , MAX([IN_DATE]) [IN_DATE], MAX([IP_DATE]) [IP_DATE]
                                    FROM(
                                                    SELECT  AG_TASK_HISTORY.FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID,
                                                    CASE WHEN (AG_TASK_HISTORY.TASK_STATUS='INFONEEDED' OR AG_TASK_HISTORY.TASK_STATUS='NEW') AND (SYSUSER.RESEARCHER_CLASS='EXTERNAL' OR SU1.RESEARCHER_CLASS ='EXTERNAL')
                                                    THEN AG_TASK_HISTORY.AG_TASK_DATE END [IN_DATE],
                                                    CASE WHEN (AG_TASK_HISTORY.TASK_STATUS='INFOPROVIDED' OR AG_TASK_HISTORY.TASK_STATUS='COMPLETE' OR AG_TASK_HISTORY.TASK_STATUS='DOCUMENTUPLOADED') AND  (SYSUSER.RESEARCHER_CLASS='EXTERNAL' OR SU1.RESEARCHER_CLASS ='EXTERNAL')
                                                    THEN AG_TASK_HISTORY.AG_TASK_DATE END AS [IP_DATE]
                                                    FROM AG_TASK_HISTORY
                                                    LEFT JOIN SYSUSER(NOLOCK) ON AG_TASK_HISTORY.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID = SYSUSER.SYSTEM_USER_ID
                                                    LEFT JOIN SYSUSER(NOLOCK) SU1 ON AG_TASK_HISTORY.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID = SU1.SYSTEM_USER_ID

                                                    WHERE AG_TASK_DATE >=CAST('01-JAN-'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE())-3 AS CHAR(4))AS DATETIME)
                                    ) A GROUP BY FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID
                    )B
    )AVT
    ON FR.FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID = AVT.FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN(
                    SELECT *, (DATEDIFF(DAY, [IN_DATE], [IP_DATE]))-
                    (DATEDIFF(WK, [IN_DATE], [IP_DATE]) * (2))-
                    (CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, [IN_DATE]) = 'SUNDAY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, [IP_DATE]) = 'SATURDAY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OTD
                    FROM
                    (
                                    SELECT FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID , MIN(CREATION_DATE) [IN_DATE], GETDATE() [IP_DATE]
                                    FROM FULFILLMENT_REQUEST WHERE CLOSED_DATE IS NULL AND AG_STATUS_ID NOT IN (29,134,142,152)
                                    GROUP BY FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID
                    )B
    ) AOT
    ON FR.FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID = AOT.FULFILLMENT_REQUEST_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSUSER SU2
    ON ATH.CF_SYSTEM_USER_ID=SU2.SYSTEM_USER_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SYSUSER SU3
    ON ATH.MODIFIED_BY_SYSTEM_USER_ID=SU3.SYSTEM_USER_ID
    WHERE SU.RESEARCHER_CLASS='EXTERNAL' AND (AVT.TAT_IN_MIN >0 OR AOT.[IP_DATE] IS NULL)
    AND ATH.AG_Task_Date >=' 2017-07-07 09:02:23.050'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you join tables and subselects you really have to know your indexes.
Use explain to check if there is a problem with using indexes.
It is possible that the query can't be optimized and has to be completely redesigned.

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to give you definite answer to your question because your query is huge and it will take long time to analyze it.

Here are some suggestions to you:

1. Get execution plan for it (copy it to SMSS and hit CTRL+L) that might give you suggestions what indexes are missing
2. Remove all the columns from the select list and leave just SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AG_TASK_HISTORY .... Check if you still have bad performance.
3. Then go from the bottom and eliminate join by join. After each elimination see if the performance is still bad.
4. After some eliminations you'll must probably get good time and that's means that you've found at least 1 bottleneck.
5. Then create a proper index for that and try again from step 2.

Other considerations would be to use stored procedures (if it possible) and split this big query into smaller parts, but I am pretty sure that with proper set of the indexes you can get much better performance than you have now.